# Inspecting the attributes on the generated field behind a field-like event

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Given the following class definition

```
public class MyClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true)]
    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

Somewhere else in my code, I would like see the attributes on the event.

```
var attributes = typeof(MyClass)
                     .GetEvents()
                     .SelectMany(n => n.GetCustomAttributes(true));
```

But I am seeing only `BrowsableAttribute` in that attributes collection.

How can I get the `field:NonSerialized` attribute info?

Comment: `GetFields` with appropriate `BindingFlags` will get you all the fields, but to go further we need to know what information you *start* with, and what information you are trying to *get to*. Do you want to be able to say: "for each field-like event, tell me the attributes on the field behind *that event*" ? Or would the answer to "are there any `NonSerialized` fields, including generated ones?" be enough? Or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `field:` syntax means that the attribute is attached to the field that is generated by the compiler (to support this field). You never get to know the name of this field, since it is an implementation detail, and it is not part of the `EventInfo` (since events do not need to be backed by a field specifically - it could be proxied, or an `EventHandlerList` etc).

If you need that level of information, you might want to implement the event manually (rather than a "field-like event", as depicted), but; in reality it is rare you would need to know this. This information is *really* only needed by `BinaryFormatter` et al, to say "hands off".

Another approach would be to use `GetFields()`, but again; no robust way of mapping fields to events exists.